# How to pass a u8 buffer to a C function in Zig?

Tags: zig

Let's say we have the following C function prototype:

```c
int do_something(char* buffer, int buff_size);
```

How do I pass a zig u8 buffer to this function? Say,

```
var buffer: [64]u8 = undefined;

_ = c_lib.do_something(buffer.ptr, 64);
```

I'm getting the error `error: no member named 'ptr' in '[64]u8'`.

How do I do this in idiomatic Zig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, this C function after being translated to Zig will look similar to this:

```
fn do_something(arg_buffer: [*c]u8, arg_buff_size: c_int) c_int;
```

`buffer` is an array (not a slice) of type `*[64]u8`.

```
var buffer: [64]u8 = undefined;
```

It doesn't have `ptr` field, but can be [type coerced](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#Type-Coercion-Slices-Arrays-and-Pointers) (implicitly cast) to `[*c]u8` pointer:

```
_ = c_lib.do_something(&buffer, buffer.len);
```

If you were using a slice, the code would've looked like this:

```
var buffer: []u8 = ...
_ = c_lib.do_something(buffer.ptr, @intCast(c_int, buffer.len));
```